# Iphone app is crashing once pushed to store but never crashes otherwise

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I know this is a very broad question, but please read through.

I have an iPhone app that is crashing when it opens a UITableViewController. It only crashes once pushed to the store (on any size or iOS version of iPhone). If I load it on the simulator it is fine. If I load it on a physical device via debug it is fine also.

What is weird is that it will open the UITableviewController the first time you click the UiTextField, but every time after that it crashes. Again all crashing is only after it is pushed to the store and is downloaded from the App store.

I am at a loss and not sure where to go from here to even try and debug it.

Here a Youtube video of the app on the simulator.
https://youtu.be/gG65eMErOWQ

Here is a video of the app on my device after downloading from the store (You cannot see the touch happending but I am clicking the lower Destination addresss field and the app crashes instantly.)

[video on device](https://youtu.be/MS3DJiwk37g)

.

Comment: did you check your app in release mode?

Comment: If you don't present a stack trace or any code, it's pretty impossible to tell you what's wrong apart from by looking into a crystal ball.

Comment: How can I present a stack trace when its from the app store. I cannot get it to crash locally from the simulator or a physical device. It only crashes when you download from the app store. Video links above being added.

Comment: Updated to show videos. Not that it will help debug. Just proof.

Comment: Don't you get the crash dumps from with the Xcode Archives & Crashes tab?

Comment: Not sure what Archives and Crashes tab is?

Comment: I have checked the app in RELEASE mode on simulator and it does crash. Not sure how to debug it though? And no stack trace shows up in RELEASE mode. In RELEASE mode if I disconnect the app form Xcode the app crashes, but if I run RELEASE mode and don't disconnet from Xcode then the app just freezes and no touches happen?

Comment: You can get the stack trace from the device log (if you run it on a device from Xcode in release mode).

Comment: If freezes on autoreleasepool with this.  Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeec443ff8)

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha Problem is FLURRY, but maybe more? I have FLURRY everywhere in my app, but never been an issue. [FlurryPageViewDelegate navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:]

Comment: I removed Flurry entirely from my app for now, but wonder if something more is wrong. Specfically around reusing a controller ref that has autoreleased? The reason the VC opens once then crashes every subsequent time.

Answer (score 0):

Ran in release mode per @dilanAnuruddha and added Crashlytics to get a report on the issue as release mode was not giving me a stack trace other than this.

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeec443ff8)
```

The issue was Flurry according to Crashlytics.

```
[FlurryPageViewDelegate navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:]
```

I believe the underlying issue is that I removed the NavigationController on this segue and go straight to the UITableViewController. Not sure how Flurry thinks it is suppose to be navigationController? Either way Flurry is completely removed from the app since I have Crashyltics now.